# Java create incremental textobject that will be written to file

Tags: java, sql, arraylist

I need some input on how to do this in a good way.

My application works today like this.

It reads a recordset from an sql server, loops through this and creates semicolon separated rows of data that it puts into an `ArrayList<String>`.

This ArrayList i send to an output class that opens a filewriter and loops through the ArrayList printing all the rows adding a linebreak to each row.

But now I want to edit the function in this way.

Recordset comes in, each time the semicolon row is completed im gonna put in some verification method on the row to check its validity. If the row is valid, then nothing above should change. But if the row isnt valid, then it should send the entire "document" (all rows that are connected to this invalid row) to an error-output.

So im looking for how to build up a good mechanism to be able to save rows of data for each loop of the recordset and then send the document (all attached rows) to either good data or bad data writer.

The trick here is that the semicolon rows that are created consists of header and X rows and sometimes Header, Subheader and then X rows. So if one of the rows fail I want all of the rows that should have been attached to that header to fall in to the error output.

I think there are better ways to apply what im trying to do and probably in a JAVA way, because i'm mainly a PHP programmer, and I started this project long ago before my JAVA skills were at the point they are now.

Comment: How do you determine that they are "connected"? Is there some sort of ID? You could use a temporary buffer and write only complete sets instead of line-by-line. For you know if the set is good or bad, when you validated all its lines, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, there is a ID keeping all the lines together. and Yes to your other question.

Comment: Can the lines come out of order? I mean for example: Line from Set1, then line from Set2, then Set1 again, Set3, Set2, Set1 ... ? How do know, a set is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would filter the rows in sql statement if the validation logic is not to complicated. 
Another approach would be to resign from semicolon representation in favor of objects, this way You can simply delete object with it's children. Consider using something like list of objects:

```
public class Data {

    private Object header;
    private Object subHeader;
    private List<Object> rowData;
    private List<Data> children;
    //Constructors, getters setters, equal, hash, toString
}
```

By building hierarchy in example a `List<Data>` You can simply delete one object(or send it anywhere you want), and by overriding toString You don't need to build string array at all. Same goes for methods like equal and hash if You need them.